# Does the seal of confession extend to bystanders?

Tags: catholicism, confession

A Catholic priest cannot reveal what someone has told him in confession. If he does reveal it, he will be defrocked and punished.

If a different Catholic than the priest unintentionally overheard the confession, and learned of something important, like a murder. Would the bystander be allowed to reveal what he had heard? Does the answer change if the bystander is also a priest?

Of course, a priest who received a confession of a murder would recommend that the person confessing should give himself up to the police. But assuming he refuses to do that, what would be expected / permissible?

This is a hypothetical question, but in the centuries since the seal of confession has existed, this must have come up.

Comment: It would be a sin of calumny or detraction to spread what one overhears from a confessional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the seal of confession extend to bystanders?

The short answer is **yes**.

No one may reveal what is said in confession.

> Another interesting side to this question is the obligation of the laity to uphold the seal of confession:  An interpreter needed for someone to make a confession or anyone who gains knowledge of a confession (such as **overhearing someone’s confession**) is also obligated to preserve secrecy (Code of Canon Law, #983.2).  For such a person to violate the secrecy of another person’s confession is a mortal sin and warrants “a just penalty, not excluding excommunication” (#1388.2).  Moreover, a person who falsely accuses a priest of breaking the seal of the confession incurs a mortal sin and perhaps other canonical penalties, including excommunication.
>
> Clearly, the Church regards the seal of confession as sacred.  Every person– whether priest or laity– must take the obligation to preserve the secrecy of confession absolutely seriously. - [Can the seal of confession be broken or the secrets ever be revealed by priests?](http://catholicstraightanswers.com/can-the-seal-of-confession-be-broken-or-the-secrets-ever-be-revealed-by-priests/)